# Unable to update Data to DB : org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

i was trying to update database tables by using following Hibernate Query Language

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String update(@RequestParam(value = "score1",required = true) String score1,
                                       @RequestParam(value = "score2",required = true) String score2,
                                       @RequestParam(value = "score3",required = true) String score3,
                                       @RequestParam(value = "score4",required = true) String score4,
                                       @RequestParam(value = "id",required = true)String id,
                                       Model model)
    {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .addAnnotatedClass(User.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(UserDetail.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(UserScores.class).buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        try
        {
            System.out.println("ID is"+id);
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.createQuery("update UserScores u set " +
                   "u.score1=:score1," +
                   "u.score2=:score2," +
                   "u.score3=:score3," +
                   "u.score4=:score4 where u.ID=:id")
                   .setParameter("score1",score1)
                   .setParameter("score2",score2)
                   .setParameter("score3",score3)
                   .setParameter("score4",score4)
                   .setParameter("id",id);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return score1+score2+score3+score4;
    }
```

after executing this code, it doesnt give any error , but the data is not updated in the database

what is the problem in executing this code

Comment: The query that you are creating needs to be executed.

Comment: And you deleted it...... https://jsfiddle.net/nogz70Lh/ tried to help, but you ran....

Comment: Thank u so much for the response . i will try it and let u know @epascarello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working, i tried it in another way

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String update(@RequestParam(value = "score1",required = true) String score1,
                                   @RequestParam(value = "score2",required = true) String score2,
                                   @RequestParam(value = "score3",required = true) String score3,
                                   @RequestParam(value = "score4",required = true) String score4,
                                   @RequestParam(value = "id",required = true)String id,
                                   Model model)
{
    SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .addAnnotatedClass(User.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(UserDetail.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(UserScores.class).buildSessionFactory();
    Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    try
    {
        session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("ID is"+id);
        UserScores userScores=session.get(UserScores.class,Integer.parseInt(id));
        userScores.setScore1((Double.parseDouble(score1)));
        userScores.setScore2((Double.parseDouble(score2)));
        userScores.setScore3((Double.parseDouble(score3)));
        userScores.setScore4((Double.parseDouble(score4)));
        session.update(userScores);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The query that you are creating needs to be executed using **query.executeUpdate()**

```
session.beginTransaction();
Query query = session.createQuery("update UserScores u set " +
                       "u.score1=:score1," +
                       "u.score2=:score2," +
                       "u.score3=:score3," +
                       "u.score4=:score4 where u.ID=:id");
query.setParameter("score1",score1)
query.setParameter("score2",score2)
query.setParameter("score3",score3)
query.setParameter("score4",score4)
query.setParameter("id",id);
query.executeUpdate();
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

An alternative way is to make changes to the persistent entities. In this case the updates will be automatically propogated.